# algorithm for the LCS of trees

Tags: string, algorithm

The LCS of two rooted, ordered, labeled trees, is the size of the largest forest that can be

obtained from both trees by deleting nodes. Deleting a node v means removing v and all edges

incident to v. The children of v become

children of the parent of v (if it exists) instead of v

I need an algorithm for computing the LCS of two equal size trees.

Comment: What's a forest? How do you define the size of a forest? if you delete the root node of a tree, do you get two new trees?

Comment: A tree is a connected, acyclic graph.  A forest is a tree that relaxes the connectedness requirement.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.cs.bgu.ac.il/~dekelts/publications/treelcs.pdf